# Name of Cocoa widget and its Qt equivalent

Tags: c++, cocoa, qt, macos

This is probably a simple question, but it's hard to Google.

What is the name of the widget / way to create a box "coming from under the window" in Cocoa? What I mean is something like the conversion interface in the Mac OS X Calculator:

[image]

And secondly, is there a widget that can do this in Qt?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sheet, as Nathanial says.

Read about how to make one in Qt on [Qt/Mac Special Features](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq18-macfeatures.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "[Sheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html)" in Cocoa.

Comment: +1, Thanks. Accepting Magnus' answer as it includes a link to a Qt-specific doc.